# redirecting output of postfix command pipe

Tags: pipe, stdout, stderr

I've created a postfix command pipe in /etc/postfix/master.cf with a valid command that produces output on STDOUT and STDERR. Everything works fine when called on a terminal (so there is output on STDOUT and STDERR) - but when letting postfix issue the command no output is shown. I wanted to test this by redirecting STDOUT and STDERR to seperate files, like so:

Sample command from /etc/postfix/master.cf
    argv=echo foo >> /tmp/test.log

The email is received and redirected to this command correctly, that's what the mail.log says anyway, but the file isn't created when postfix receives an email.

Anyone knows why this happens?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The [pipe(8) documentation](http://www.postfix.org/pipe.8.html) explains why this happens:

> **argv**=*command...* (required)
>                The command to be executed. This must be specified as  the  last
>                command attribute.  The command is executed directly, i.e. without interpretation of shell meta characters by a  shell  command
>                interpreter.

No interpretation by a shell means the redirect won't work. Instead the `>>` and `/tmp/test.log` simply end up as additional arguments to `echo`.

According to the documentation Postfix >= 3.0 allows quoting whitespace in arguments with "{" and "}", so the following should work:

```
argv=/bin/sh -c { echo foo >> /tmp/test.log }
```

I still have to find an inline solution that works with Postfix < 3. ATM I resort to invoking a wrapper shell script that in turn sets up the redirect.

Comment: My argv line already has { . I tried adding another set for log redirection as per your suggestion but that did not work. I also tried the other recommendation for wrapper shell but even that did not work. I am guessing it could be more for postfix permissions. So I created the log file and gave it chmod 777 but still nothing gets logged there.